# Recursive Function to reverse Linked List not working

Tags: c++, function, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to print a linked list in reverse order using recursion, but I think the logic is not right as the output only gives me the first node of the original list, nothing else.

This is the function

```
void reverseListRec(node *&head1){

    node *temp = head1;

    if(temp == NULL || temp -> next == NULL ){
        head1 = temp;
        return;
    }

    reverseListRec(head1 -> next);
    temp -> next -> next = temp; 
    temp -> next = NULL;
    return;
}
```

This is the part where I call it.

```
node *head = NULL;
cin>>head;
reverseListRec(head);
cout<<head<<endl;
```

I have used operator overloading to input and output the LinkedList which is working fine, but after the recursive call is where the problem starts.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Edit :-
[image]

Comment: Draw the linked list with a pencil on a piece of paper. Simulate what your program does by erasing some arrows and drawing other arrows. Assume there are 5 nodes. Assume that the *recursive* call works correctly. What does the top-level call do?

Comment: I did. I can not figure out what’s incorrect.

Comment: Please show the pictures.

Comment: Edited in the question.

Comment: Why not just use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

Comment: It doesn't look like you used a pencil and an eraser. Fine, but then you need a separate complete picture of the state of your program after each step. I can help you a bit: https://pasteboard.co/P2NoC9J38ZZ9.png These are your states before and after the recursive call `reverseListRec(head1 -> next);` (assuming it worked). Now draw a complete picture of the state after `temp -> next -> next = temp;` and then once again after `temp -> next = NULL;`.
`

Comment: Updated here : https://pasteboard.co/SpkmFwVmIC0b.jpg

Comment: This is almost correct, except how come `head`` now points at a different node? Where is it changed? How could it possibly jump all the way to 1? And why do you have two pointers coming out of node 4? At any rate you now see that the code doesn't do what it needs to do, not even close. You need to create a link from node 1 to node 0, but node 1 is far away. Consider a helper function that reverses the list and returns the head *and the tail* of the reversed list.

Comment: Updated here : https://pasteboard.co/ZmUAKSKVdeyW.jpg

Comment: Head1 points to 1 because of the statement inside the base class of the function. When there is only one element left the head gets updated to the last element which is what is required.

Comment: That's the whole point of the question, how can I do this with the help of a void function without having to return the head?

Comment: "Head1 points to 1 because of the statement inside the base class of the function" Nope. The recursive call cannot update `head1` from the top-level invocation. It gets its own `head1`.

Comment: "That's the whole point of the question, how can I do this with the help of a void function" These words are not in the question so I fail to see how they are the point of it. As far as I can see, the original question is "what's wrong with my code", which you have successfully answered yourself. Why do you need to do this with such a pointless restriction anyway?

Comment: That is what i am failing to understand. I have passed head1 by reference, so shouldn't head1 be updating to that temp value?

Comment: The thing is I approached this problem with the void implementation, so that is why I need help in figuring out what is wrong and if there is any correction that can be made

Comment: You passed `head` by reference to the top-level call, where it is called `head1`. You passed `head1->next` by reference to the next-level call, where it is called `head1`, and it's a different `head1`. You cannot have the same `head1` to be both `head` and `head->next` at the same time. If you cannot visualize this, it's a good time to start learning how to use a debugger. (Actually yesterday was an even better time).

Comment: I'm sorry I overlooked the obvious. It is possible (and easy) to have a recursive reversal function not returning the new tail, because you already have the new tail (it's just head1->next). You just need to update the head properly.

Comment: @AnuragHale Why did you tag this question with `dsa`?  Did you read what the `dsa` tag is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you only change `head1` when reaching the base case of recursion, but since in the recursive case you don't pass `head1` itself as argument to the recursive call, there is no way that `head1` is going to change. What is changed is `head1 -> next`. So you actually never change the original head of the list.

Here is a correction of the part that deals with the recursive case:

```
    // Update `head1` here too
    head1 = head1 -> next;
    // And have the recursion update head1 itself
    reverseListRec(head1); 
    temp -> next -> next = temp;
    temp -> next = NULL;
```

Comment: I am failing to understand this. I am passing head1 as a reference in the function call, so shouldn't the actual memory which I am referencing be changing when I make that base case statement?
Is this not similar to when you add a new element at the head of a LL and you pass the head as a reference so that it's value is changed?

Comment: *"I am passing head1 as a reference"*: no, in the recursive call you are **not** passing `head1`, but `head1->next`. So what changes is the pointer at `head1->next`. `head1` doesn't change.

Comment: So is there any need to pass the head as a reference in the argument when the call is made?

Comment: Sure, how else will the original caller see its `head1` changed?